# How to create a grouping key in D3js that is a combination of two JSON attributes

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to build a dynamic grouped and stacked chart using D3js. I have several check boxes, which I use to group the data according to different data attributes. One of the grouping is by two `JSON` attributes: `quantity` and `type`. I have the following `JSON` data:

> [      {
>         "period":201408,
>         "quantity":10,
>         "type":"week",
>         "sum":55.5     },     {
>         "period":201408,
>         "quantity":3,
>         "type":"month",
>         "sum":150     },
>       {
>         "period":201408,
>         "quantity":12,
>         "type":"month",
>         "sum":150     } ]

This is my ordinary nest function:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
             .key(function(d) { return d[groupBy]; });

<input type = "checkbox" name ="groupBy" value="someValue">
```

So, in this case I should have three groups: 10 week, 3 month and 12 month. I'm trying to make a separate case to nest the data, but I don't know how to make the key to be a combination of two attributes. I'm doing something like:

```
var nest = d3.nest();
if(groupBy === "specialValue"){ // groupBy is the value of the selected checkbox
    // get a key  - combination of quantity and type....I don't know how
       groupBy = key;
        nest.key(function(d) { return d[groupBy]; });   
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your array is in a var named `data`. Then

```
var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.quantity + ' ' + d.type })

var grouped = nest.map(data)
```

will produce `grouped` like this

```
{
   "10 week": [ { "period":201408, "quantity":10, "type":"week", "sum":55.5 } ],
   "3 month": [ { "period":201408, "quantity":3, "type":"month", "sum":150 } ],
   "12 month": [ { "period":201408, "quantity":3, "type":"month", "sum":150 } ]
}
```

so that you can say `grouped["10 week"]` and get an array all the objects (one, in this case) that have `"quantity": 10` AND `"type": "week"`. Maybe that's what you're interested in(?).

Alternatively, you can:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.quantity })
  .key(function(d) { return d.type });

var grouped = nest.map(data)
```

which will produce

```
{
  "week": {
    "10": [ { "period":201408, "quantity":10, "type":"week", "sum":55.5 } ]
  },
  "month": {
    "3": [ { "period":201408, "quantity":3, "type":"month", "sum":150 } ],
    "12 month": [ { "period":201408, "quantity":12, "type":"month", "sum":150 } ]
  }
}
```

and you can say `grouped["week"]["10"]` to get the same result from above.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write nest function like below , for details, please refer : [this link](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/)

```js
var nest = d3.nest()
             .key(function(d) { return d.quality})
             .key(function(d) {return d.type});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't need to nest twice.